# Usage of SimpleDateFormat for converting microseconds

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, simpledateformat

I have date data in the db in the following format:

```
 07-FEB-18 09.43.51.712992 AM
```

But the incoming input format is :

```
2018-02-07T09:43:51.712992
```

So I converted my input to the expected format to be able to check against db value. Here is the some piece of my code snippet.

```
 public class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSSSSS aa",Locale.ENGLISH);  
            strDate = "2018-02-07T09:43:51.712992"
            String year = strDate.substring(2,4);
            String month = CommonUtil.getMonthValueWithLetters(strDate.substring(5,7));
            String day = strDate.substring(8,10);
            String hour = CommonUtil.convertToPMAM(strDate.substring(11,13)).keySet().iterator().next();
            String min = strDate.substring(14,16);
            String second = strDate.substring(17,19);
            String milliSecond = strDate.substring(20,26);
            String AMPM = CommonUtil.convertToPMAM(strDate.substring(11,13)).values().iterator().next();
            String convertedStrDate = day + "-" + month + "-" + year + " " + hour + "." + min + "." + second + "." + milliSecond + " " + AMPM; //07-FEB-18 09.43.51.712992 AM
            Date timeStamp = dateFormat.parse(convertedStrDate);  //Wed Feb 07 09:55:43 GMT+04:00 2018          
        } 
    }   

    public class Commonutil{
        public static String getMonthValueWithLetters(String month){
            switch(month){
                case "01": return "JAN";
                case "02": return "FEB";
                case "03": return "MAR";
                case "04": return "APR";
                case "05": return "MAY";
                case "06": return "JUN";
                case "07": return "JUL";
                case "08": return "AUG";
                case "09": return "SEP";
                case "10": return "OCT";
                case "11": return "NOV";
                case "12": return "DEC";
                default : return null;              
                }
        }
        public static   Map<String, String> convertToPMAM(String hour){
                Map<String, String> keyValues  = new HashMap<String, String>();
                int value = Integer.parseInt(hour);
                if( value <=12){
                    keyValues.put(hour, "AM");
                        return keyValues;
                    }else{
                        int temp = value - 12;
                        if(temp<10){
                            keyValues.put("0"+String.valueOf(value-12),"PM");
                            }
                        else{
                            keyValues.put(String.valueOf(value-12), "PM");
                            }
                        }        
                        return keyValues; 
                    }   
                }
```

As it seems parse method converts microseconds as well so whenever I pass this value to the db , it can not be checked against the value in the db. So is there any way that I can convert my incoming date value to the required format shown in the db?

For your information I am using jdbc and oracle db.

Comment: Isn't date field in your database of type `Date`? If so, shouldn't you just convert the input into date and then compare?

Comment: @Plirkee Nope it is Oracle type TimeStamp

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You are greatly overcomplicating things. Your incoming format, `2018-02-07T09:43:51.712992`, matches that required by the one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse(String)`, so use this. With a just fairly new JDBC driver you should be able to store your `LocalDateTime` into the timestamp column of your Oracle database. No need for any conversion in your Java code.

Comment: It’s unclear to me, what exactly do you mean by “check against db value”? Are you using the incoming date-time in a query? Or comparing it to a timestamp retrieved from the database? Should it be the same, before, after…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.Date` only has an accuracy of milliseconds. If you need a higher accuracy when dealing with a database (down to one nanosecond), you will have to use the `java.sql.Timestamp` class instead. By replacing the 'T' separator between date and time in your input format, you can feed the string directly to a factory method and get the expected result:

`Timetstamp t = Timestamp.valueOf("2018-02-07T09:43:51.712992".replace('T', ' '));`

You can then use the timestamp directly in your JDBC statements.

Comment: Alternatively, one could use a `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you are getting input in a format like `2018-02-07T09:43:51.712992`, and you need to compare this input to timestamps in your Oracle database.

Your input string conforms with ISO 8601. The classes of `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, parse ISO 8601 format as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter. This makes parsing your input easy:

```
    String inputString = "2018-02-07T09:43:51.712992";
    LocalDateTime inputDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(inputString);
```

Using a JDBC 4.2 compliant JDBC driver (which you probably already have and can at least get for your Oracle database) you can pass this `LocalDateTime` directly to your query. I am assuming your query is represented as a `PreparedStatement` in Java. For example:

```
    yourPreparedStatement.setObject(1, inputDateTime);
```

Now you can compare the input value directly with timestamps from the database in your query. No need for your format conversion.

But as answer to your title: no, `SimpleDateFormat` cannot support microseconds. It only has a precision of milliseconds.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is a nice hack! But I have inherited code base , so i am not supposed to use java.time  API

Comment: A funny restriction, IMHO (not to say absurd). So you are not allowed to write the most readable and maintainable code? Use of `java.time` here can coexist nicely with whatever is already in your codebase (and might be a first step in a long lasting transition to the better future). If that were me, I’d prefer to challenge what I was supposed and not supposed to use. I’m not saying it’ll get you anywhere where you are, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass that string into Oracle, you can convert it to a timestamp:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-07T09:43:51.712992', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.FF6') from dual;
```

Or, adding a timezone to the string:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-02-07T09:43:51.712992 -5:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.FF6 TZH:TZM') from dual;
```

Put the "T" separator in double quotes might be the tricky part thats not obvious.  The Oracle format docs are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#BABEFHFG).  The timezone support docs are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG004).